# ssh tunneling lmgrd port what I've missed?

Tags: linux, ssh, tcp, ssh-tunnel

I've got 2 machines: one local , one flexserver
I'd like to do a ssh connection for forwarding the TCP port of the flexserver.
On the flexserver, `lmutil lmstat -c 5280@localhost` is working fine

So I launched the ssh tunneling connection:

```
ssh -N -L 5280:flexserver:5280 user@flexserver
```

On the local machine where the ssh connection is launched I tried:

```
lmutil lmstat -c 5280@localhost
lmutil - Copyright (c) 1989-2012 Flexera Software LLC. All Rights Reserved.
Flexible License Manager status on Wed 4/15/2015 17:10

License server status: 5280@flexserver
    License file(s) on flexserver: 5280@localhost:

lmgrd is not running: Cannot connect to license server system. (-15,570:115 "Operation now in progress")
```

Any Idea what i missed or did wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check on you local machine port 5280 is still not used (netstat -an | grep 5280). Check also on flexserver if 5280 port is bind to all ip addresses or just to localhost, if it is bind to localhost you will need to change your ssh command to

```
ssh -N -L 5280:127.0.0.1:5280 user@flexserver
```

Of course don't exit your ssh session to flexserver until you perform the `lmutil lmstat -c 5280@localhost`

Comment: After opening the SSH. Can you check if you have port 5280 listening on your local machine?